# How to set XmlReader with HttpWebResponse

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xmlreader, httpwebresponse

I've been having an issue taking a HttpWebResponse and setting it to an XmlReader, with the examples I've looked up so far I've gotten this:

```
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
XmlReader xmlReader;
if (response != null)
{
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
    //string st = sr.ReadToEnd().Trim();
    xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(sr);
}
```

But the problem is that xmlReader does not get filled with the entire response, I get a partial response that isn't even valid XML(no closing tags on some nodes) which causes issues when trying to read from that variable later on.

But if I uncomment the following line for testing:

```
string str = sr.ReadtoEnd().Trim();
```

The variable str is filled with the entire XML response, but obviously I need it in a form of a XmlReader so I can run LINQ to XML on it.

My question is, what is the best way to be sure that I get the entire response in the XmlReader object?

Comment: You can try UTF-8 encoding: StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8); see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.getresponsestream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this doesn't solve the actual problem, but may help you reach the goal to be able to use LINQ-to-XML on the XML downloaded.

Using `XmlReader` isn't the only way to be able to run LINQ-to-XML. Given that you're able to get full XML in the string variable `str`, you can then use [`XElement.Parse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [`XDocument.Parse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to load the string to LINQ-to-XML's `XElement` or `XDocument` object :

```
.....
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
string str = sr.ReadToEnd().Trim();
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(str);
//at this point you can continue doing necessary LINQ-to-XML operations
.....
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, completely forgot I could run the same LINQ to XML on an XDocument. Chalking it up to tunnel vision.